# Vue3 Composables in NPM Package

Tags: npm, vuejs3, vite

I am attempting to make an NPM Package to share some Vue3 Components. I have the following to register the components themselves.

```
import components from "./components/components";

const plugin = {
  install (Vue) {
    for (const prop in components) {
      if (components.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        const component = components[prop]
        Vue.component(component.name, component)
      }
    }
    
  }
}
```

But I also have some functions (composables) that I would like to make available as well. What is the correct way to do this? Is there a similar setup to the component install?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Composable are just JavaScript functions. You can export them from a file and make the file available through [`exports`](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#exports) key in `package.json`.

Here an example taken from from [VueUse](https://github.com/vueuse/vueuse/blob/main/packages/core/package.json#L23)

```json
 "exports": {
    ".": {
      "types": "./index.d.ts",
      "require": "./index.cjs",
      "import": "./index.mjs"
    },
    "./*": "./*",
    "./metadata": {
      "types": "./metadata.d.ts",
      "require": "./metadata.cjs",
      "import": "./metadata.mjs"
    }
  },
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out. Seems to not be much documentation on this type of thing but I will keep looking.

Comment: I know this was answered but have you tried using provide/inject? Inside the install function you have access to the vue instance.  There you can use provide to add the function.  Then in your components setup function you can inject it.